# How to improve joining performance in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using left join between codeigniter and 2 tables. My goal is to find data in the "stock" table that is not in the "products" table. But how can I speed it up very slowly?

**Row numbers in the table**

```
stok - 35,353 line
urunler - 167,445 line
```

```php
 public function kitapKontrol()
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->select('stok.isbn,urunler.isbn');
        $this->db->from('stok');
        $this->db->join('urunler', 'urunler.isbn = stok.isbn','left');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $query;
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }
```

result process

```php
$kitaplar = $this->api_model->kitapKontrol();
print_r($kitaplar);
```

Comment: you want to use a left outer join, read this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/. Besides that, if a query is slow, it most often means your database structure is wrong. make sure you have indexes set for stok and urunler. if you have multiple joins, the sequence of your joins can change the query speed significantly, too

Comment: Can you access the database directly?  You need to index urunler->isbn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do re-check for you tables index, or try to do re-index your tables